# jQuery image change via input title

Tags: jquery

Using a select dropdown I can replace a main image with the onchange content of value=""

```
<select name="dropper" id="dropper">
<option value="pl2.jpg" title="pl2.jpg">Design 2</option>
<option value="pl4.jpg" title="pl4.jpg" >Design 4</option>
</select>

<div id="SWAPview"></div>
```

using

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#dropper").change(function() {
    var src = $(this).val();

    $("#SWAPview").html(src ? "<img src='" + src + "'>" : "");
    });
});
```

In the live script I can't use the value="" so was looking at the title="" attribute but going around in circles. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean "live script"? Like it works locally but not on your server? Are you sure the path to the image is correct?

Comment: I am just playing with this as a basic HTML page  to get it to work. The final script is going into an e-commerce page where the value="" is pulled from the database.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can access element property values via `prop` or `attr`. As you astutely noticed, the `val` property no longer works because the select element does not take on the title of the option. Instead you can search its children and filter on the selected using `:selected`. You will want to get the select option before retrieving this though.

```
$("#dropper").change(function() {
    var src = $(this).children('option').filter(':selected').prop('title'); //jquery 1.7+
    var src = $(this).children('option').filter(':selected').attr('title'); //jquery < 1.7

    $("#SWAPview img").prop('src', src);
});
```

I updated my answer based on this feedback from the jQuery documentation.

> Because :selected is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS
>   specification, queries using :selected cannot take advantage of the
>   performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll()
>   method. To achieve the best performance when using :selected to select
>   elements, first select the elements using a pure CSS selector, then
>   use .filter(":selected").

Comment: Brilliant - thank you for such a speedy reply, would never have solved that in a month of Sundays. Cheers.

Comment: @user1173703 - You are very welcome. I also just noticed that setting the image `src` attribute can be optimized. You don't have to call `html()` and do an entire replace. Instead grab the image element with a selector and then set its new src value with `prop` or `attr`.

Comment: I get a DOM error with the above change to the image replace $("#SWAPview img").prop is not a function

Comment: @user1173703 - you must be using < jQuery 1.7 then. You need to use `attr` in that case. If you ever start using jQuery 1.7 then you should go through your code and switch `attr` to `prop`.

Comment: Thank you so much - that is now firing fine.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
<select>
    <option value="1" data-x="image-1.jpg">Iran</option>
    <option value="2" data-x="image-2.jpg">Irak</option>
    <option value="3" data-x="image-3.jpg">Afganistan</option>
</select>

$('select').find('option').click(function()
{
    var image = $(this).attr( 'data-x' );
    $('#content').empty().append('<img style="display:none" src="+ image +" title="Thumb" alt="Thumb"/>');

    //Load and Show
    $('#content').find('img').load(function(){
        $(this).fadeIn(250);
    });

});
```

Read this:
http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/

Comment: I wouldn't add click events to every option. It is safer to monitor the `change` event of the select list. Option values can be selected by clicking, typing or programmatically. You want those use cases to work also. Also, adding click many events is inefficient. That being said, I agree that `data` attribute is a better way for storing information, although OP didn't specify it.